# How to bind ctrl-up/ctrl-down in irssi?

Tags: irssi

Trying to bind a command to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>up</kbd>, but `/bind ^up` doesn't work the way I expect. I'm guessing it's being parsed as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I opened a terminal, issued `cat` without parameters and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>. This generated the key codes `^[Oa` and `^[Ob` for me (do it yourself, the exact codes can rely on terminal, etc.). I then pasted this into irssi as

```
/bind ^[Oa next_window
/bind ^[Ob previous_window
```

and now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> goes to the next/previous window respectively.

Comment: When I try this - I get the same codes for `Up` and `ctrl-up`.

Comment: Which terminal do you use? Do you run it through tmux/GNU Screen/PuTTY/similar? If you get the same key codes (in the same environment as irssi), then you **can not** bind them separately, so this needs to be fixed. If you are using e.g. tmux, you should add `set-window-option -g xterm-keys on` in your `~/.tmux.conf` to catch more key codes, and similar options might exist for other configurations.

Comment: screen/putty. Is there a similar option for screen?

Comment: Search and ye shall find :-) : http://serverfault.com/questions/130128/using-ctrl-arrow-keys-with-putty-and-screen

Comment: the easiest way to find the code is by running `cat` and then typing the desired combo